Why Spoc is not mocking the beans in controllerSpec if bean is annotated with Autowired in Controller in grails 5
I am writing unit tests in Grails 5 for my OtpController using Spoc, which has an OtpService bean annotated with @Autowired. I am mocking the OtpService in OtpControllerSpec (the unit test class). When I run the unit test, I get the error below. However, when I run the application, all the beans load without any errors.
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myproject.OtpController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'otpService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'myproject.OtpService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
Ideally the error shouldn't come as I am mocking the beans. Help me to resolve this.
